# How to set username and password for login page in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 15px;">
      <img src="../assets/images/girmiti.png" />
    </div>
    <v-form>
      <v-row>
        <v-col offset-md="4">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="E-mail"
            rounded
            filled
            required
            style="width:400px;"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col offset-md="4">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            rounded
            filled
            style="width:400px;"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
       
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col style="text-align: center">
          <v-btn color="success" class="mr-4" @click="validate"> Login </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-form>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    email: "test",
    password: "test",
  }),
  methods: {
    validate() {
      
      this.$router.push('/questionMaster');
      
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have a basic login form. i want to set email and password. So that user can login using some credentials. But at present i have button. Where if user clicked on it. it simple redirects to another page without checking user and password.

in the validate method, how to set the email, password so that user give credentials and login.

Comment: the warning is interesting: *Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration* -

Comment: the there's this error `Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Comment: then `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: can't access property "replace", this.$router is undefined"`

Comment: then `TypeError: can't access property "replace", this.$router is undefined`

Comment: browser developer tools console is where to look for errors

Comment: I have added router dependency also now. But still cant see any ui screen.
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lake-nq4gc?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Any reference/ codesandbox link for login redirect to sample page with router.

Comment: you still have errors - are you even looking in your browser *developer* tools? that's where the action is

Comment: @Bravo Do you have any reference link or codesandbox links for login page with redirection to another page in Vuejs.